# spring boot transactional doesn't rollback with multiple objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i have a problem with my transaction.
i have 4 entities - entityA, entityB, entityC and entityD - all are different objects (for different tables in my DB).
for each of them i have a repository that looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface entityXRepository extends JPARepository<entityX, Long> {}
```

(entityX is any of the above)
and i also have a service for every of the entityB, entityC, entityD, which looks like:

```
@Service
public class entityXService {
    @Autowired
    entityXRepository repository;

    public entityX save(entityX toSave) {
        return repository.save(toSave);
    }
}
```

as you can see i don't use @transactional on the save.

and my service for entityA looks like this:

```
@Service
public class entityAService {
    @Autowired
    entityARepository repository;

    public entityA save(entityA toSave) {
       return repository.save(toSave);
    }

    public void doSomeStuff(...) throws Exception {
        // do a lot of stuff and create entities for A,B,C,D and i throw exception 
        //if something happens here

        saveAllToDB(entityAToSave, entityBToSave, entityCToSave, entityDToSave);
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = "Exception.class")
    public void saveAllToDB(entityA a, entityB b, entityC c, entityD d) {
        serviceA.save(a);
        if(b != null) {
          serviceB.save(b);
        }
        if(c != null) {
          serviceC.save(c);
        }
        if(d != null) {
          serviceD.save(d);
        }
    }
}
```

in doSomeStuff i get input from the client and create the entities, and if the input violate some rule i throw exception with message to the user.
as you can see only the saveAllToDB is Transactional.
when there is an exception in saving one of the entities like entityD there is no rollback only an exception being thrown to the error controller and entity A to B are saved in the DB. (to check this, i entered to D a number with 12 digits, and the db column is 10 digits)

i tired putting @Transactional on all of the save functions in the services but it didn't work either.
can anyone help me?

Comment: You do not have to pass the `Exception.class` for `rollbackFor ` as a String. Pass it as a class. Secondly, what is your `generation strategy` for the IDs for your entities? If you ID rely on the underlying database autogenerated ID, then hibernate will insert the value immediately which is not part of the transaction. You can change the generation strategy to `GenerationType.TABLE` and let Hibernate manage the ID - This will allow the entity to be part of the transaction.

Comment: @hido, How are you injecting `serviceA`, `serviceB` and `serviceC` used in the method `saveAllToDB`. Is `serviceA` the instance of  same class ?

Comment: As far as I understand, you rely on the underlying database restrictions to do your validation. I would encourage you to do the validation within Java and only use the database validation as an additional precaution. This will limit the database interaction and you can fail faster if the entities violate some rule.

Comment: You do not have to put `@Transactional` on all your methods. The default `propagation` is `Propagation.REQUIRED`. So you just have to put the annotation on the base method which you want to be transactional. All the nested methods that are part of your transactional method will join the transaction.

Comment: maybe you should also post your client code... the code invoking saveAllToDB method. Besides that your saveAllToDB method delegates calls to other services (in your code excerpt those services aren't wired either, I guess you left out some part of the code)... in general, it's common practice to demark transactions on service level (that's what you've done) and inside the service methods delegate to one or more repository instances... so I'd wire up all needed repositories inside your service (with @Autowired just as you did for entityRepositoryA) and use these inside saveAllToDB()....

Comment: I inject serviceB, serviceC and serviceD with @Autowired.